# View badges on another person's profile page

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, badges, profile-page

Is there any way to see the badges of the user whose profile I am currently viewing? I can see all the badges listed but there is no way to see a summary that is behind every post that this person has made.

Answer (score 6):

You can view badges of another user from:

1. User's profile page > Badges tab
2. User's profile page > Activity tab (then filtered on badges)

For example, lets see [summary of Jeff Atwood's badges](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood?tab=badges) or Jeff's badges [in chronological order](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood?tab=activity&sort=badges). If you click on any badge on this list, you get a list of posts on which that badge was awarded, for example, [Jeff's Great Answer posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood?tab=activity&sort=badges).

Comment: +1 for great answer, but you must admit.. [Jon Skeet badges](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet?tab=activity#page_1-filter_badges) are much more interesting! :D

Comment: That's also working from the Badge summary, as far as I can see.

Answer (score 5):

It's been a while since this was implemented so let's go over all the ways you can view the badges of any user. We've had some profile reworks since the earlier answers so some of the links aren't quite correct.

You can access a list of all of their badges in the [Badges tab of the profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23354/marc-gravell?tab=badges). This can be sorted by a variety of means, and also groups together multiple copies of the same badge. You can investigate which posts yielded each badge by [clicking on the badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/25/great-answer?userid=23354) where appropriate.

A short version of this list is also available on the Summary tab. This also links to the Badges tab.

In the Activity tab of a profile, you can also [trawl through a chronological organization of when they earned each of their badges](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23354/marc-gravell?tab=activity&sort=badges). It will not tell you which posts earned each badge, but as with the main list, you can click on relevant badges to see the full selection of posts that earned them the badge (which is from most to least recent).

Answer (score 4):

If you mean the badge summary that appears on every post:

[image: Jon Skeet summary]

Then you can see it in the *accounts* tab of the profile, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet?tab=accounts

Which will show you:

[image: Jon Skeet badges]